# Type constraint lost when invoking function with the same return type, is there a way to enforce it?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, inferred-type

### TLDR:

I am having issues with forcing TSC to constrain the return type of my curried function call, that is as short and abstract as I can define it.

Issues with type information not being properly constrained can be seen on this [TSPlayground](https://tsplay.dev/WKbbMm) link, if you just want to look at types and get a brief information. I've left in comments in that code (its not too long, but should assist in understanding). Otherwise, lets dive deep:

##### Section 1: Context (skip to the following section if you are familiar with Redux and Reselect)

We have a Selector:

```js
type Selector<S = any, R = unknown> = (state: S) => R
```

which is a simple input output function, state comes in and something comes out. Conceptually there could be computation inside of a selector, which means that you'd want to cache the results and only re-compute on state change, however, due to Redux's philosophy of immutability, the state ALWYAS changes, so there is no caching, which is perfectly fine if you are only working with simple selectors such as:

```
state => state.foo
```

for more complex cases we have a function `createSelector` which has a signature as follows

```js
//pseudocode
function createSelector<T extends Selectors[]>(...dependencies: T, resultFn: (...args: ReturnType<T>) => R) => R
```

now obviously this type cannot work in typescript but I think it conveys the idea, the function is suppose to take in other selectors, and a "resultFn" which takes the result of the selectors and produces a computed result. All the "hard computation" should be inside the resultFn, which should be cached based on the result of the selectors, this way, simple selectors will re-run (due to immutability) but the computation heavy (resultFn) function will not. This is the principle upon which the reselect library is based.

##### Section 2: Improving on Reselect

Since I am making a Redux extension (sort of) I have all my selectors defined in a controlled environment, which means that I can reference them using only strings, or rather, each named selector is defined:

```js
interface DEFINED_SELECTORS {
    selectFoo: number
    selectBar: string
}

type SELECTOR_NAMES = keyof DEFINED_SELECTORS

type SelectorResult<T> = T extends SELECTOR_NAMES ? DEFINED_SELECTORS[T] : never
```

This allows us to accept not only `Selector`s as dependencies for our cacheable selector function, but also strings (or rather `SELCTOR_NAMES`). As such we define our dependency as follows:

```js
type Dependency<S = any> = SELECTOR_NAMES | Selector<S>
```

The original `createSelector` function, as defined in Reselect has a signature that goes as follows:

```js
function createSelector([dep1 [, dep2[, dep3[, depN ...]]]], resultFn)
```

with the N number of optional dependencies preceding a required result function parameter.

To my knowledge, this kind of type is not definable in typescript, thus I have tried using something along the lines of:

```js
function createSelector([dep1 [, dep2 [, dep3 [, depN ...]]]]) (resultFn)
```

It may be worth noting that the `resultFn` in both cases accepts results of invoking dependency functions as its arguments, meaning that the number of dependencies passed to `createSelector` corresponds to the number of arguments the `resultFn` will recieve, with their types being the results of invoking those dependencies. The return type of the resultFn then becomes the return type of a selector created by the function. And with that, we have finally reached our desired type for the `createSelector` function, as follows:

```js
function createSelector<S, T extends Array<Dependency<S>>>(
  ...args: T
): <R>(
  callback: (
    ...args: {
      [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends SELECTOR_NAMES
        ? SelectorResult<T[I]>
        : ReturnType<Exclude<T[I], SELECTOR_NAMES>>
    }
  ) => R
) => Selector<S, R>
```

##### Section 3: Using the `createSelector` function

Now, when this function is invoked, the result is a `Selector<S,R>` where the type of the `R` type-argument is whichever type was returned by the `resultFn`, so if we were to do something like:

```js
interface DEFINED_SELECTORS {
    selectFoo: number
    selectBar: string
}

type ExampleState = {
    foo: number
    bar: string
}

// mouseover: Selector<unknown, ExampleState>
const selectState = createSelector("selectFoo", "selectBar")((foo, bar): ExampleState => ({ foo, bar }))
```

Logically the `R` is now `ExampleState` however the type of a type-argument `S` is `unknown`, which makes sense, and this is where this little thing comes in:

```js
type SelectorInitializer = (cfg: {
    state: ExampleState
    selectors: Record<string, Selector<ExampleState>>
}) => void // type is void just for example, realistically it wouldn't be void

declare const init: SelectorInitializer
```

So now we can use:

```js
init({
    state: {
        foo: 123,
        bar: 'stringy'
    },
    selectors: {
        selectFoo: state => state.foo, // this is a selector 
        selectBar: state => state.bar, // this is also a selector
        notASelector: 123, // this is not a selector, so it causes errors

        // which then clearly means this is a selector, as it causes no errors
        // works, however, if we mouseover the property we notice that it this Selector's
        // type argument `S` remains unknown, whilst `selectFoo` and `selectBar` were constrained
        selectFizz: createSelector('selectBar', "selectFoo")((bar, foo) => "fizz"),

        // which is not an issue when using `string` dependencies, like shown above
        // however when we do decide to use Selector type (function) dependencies.... 
        // it obviously causes an error, as the state is "unknown"
        selectBuzz: createSelector("selectFoo", state => state.bar, state => 123)((foo, bar, num) => num),
    }
})
```

So for some reason, the constraint put in place within the `SelectorInitializer` doesn't apply to these selectors created with `createSelector` function, even though it infact does constrain the object properties to be a `Selector` type....

What makes matters worse is, if we change our `createSelector` function's type a bit by removing the `resultFn` part (for the sake of experimenting), and instead immidiatly return a `Selector`, the type-argument `S` gets properly constrained, however now we are missing the `R` as obviously, we did not define it anywhere...

```js
declare function createSelector<S, R, T extends Dependency<S>[]>(
    ...args: T
): Selector<S, R>

init({
    state: {
        bar: '123',
        foo: 123
    },
    selectors: {
        selectBuzz: createSelector("selectFoo", state => state.bar, state => 123)
    }
})
```

##### Section 4: The ISSUE

So I am confused, as TSC clearly wants to, and has no issue, constraining the `Selector` type when it is returned by the `createSelector` function.... however, when it is returned by a a curried function, it suddenly is no longer able to do so.

What am I missing here? Why are we able to constrain a `Selector` type returned by `createSelector(...)` whilst simultaneously not one returned by `createSelector(...)(...)` and more importantly, how to fix this?

I am also open to suggestions involving changing the function signatures, maybe the curried style I went for (due to not being able to have mixed `...arg` types where N optional `Dependency` arguments precede a required `resultFN` argument) is wrong and you have a better idea?

Take a look at all the types on the [TSPlayground](https://tsplay.dev/WKbbMm) link.

Lastly,
I've tried to reduce this issue to a minimum reproducible example, and this is what I came up with... the actual `createSelector` function is not suppose to return a selector rather a `DeferredSelector` (you can see the type in the TSPlayground), so the constraint put in place by the `SelectorInitializer` should be expanded to accept a `Record` of `Selector | DeferredSelector` but that opens a whole other can of worms, which I am hoping I will work once this inference works, though it might be worth keeping in mind.

Hope the wall of text is not too much to read, I feel like I could remove Section 1, if the community thinks that the context is not necessary for the issue at hand.

Comment: Not sure of this is what you're after but variadic signatures with trailing functions are definitely possible `type Args<TArgs extends any[]> = [...TArgs, (...args: TArgs) => any];
declare function f<FA extends any[]>(...args: Args<FA>): any;
f(1, '2', false, (x, y, z) => { console.log({ x, y, z }); });`

Comment: I will see if this implementation works for me, I tried to do that and apply the constraints earlier but I couldn't manage il give it another go, the issue presented above is mainly not related to this solution that you proposed, but this solution is an alternative that might open up the issue from a different angle

Comment: I've managed to sort of implement this in the most simple example I have, I will now try with my real types, it might be the solution to my problem.

Comment: You're trying to push contextual typing farther than it can go; you expect generic type argument inference to be delayed until the result of the generic function itself is called, which can't happen. Unless you can rephrase your operations so that inference proceeds in a forwards-in-time direction I expect you'll be stuck. I made a brief attempt [at this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wgGG4w) to make the scope of `S` closer to where it's used so that it only needs one layer of contextual typing instead of two, but it's ‍♂️ and ultimately I doubt this will work without a sizable refactoring.

Comment: Hmmmph, I've tried using the approach Aluan Haddad suggested, opting to not have function currying but rather define the `createSelector` as a function which intakes both dependencies and the computation heavy result function.... which sort of works, but not fully.... Do you people think it would be possible to make it that way?

Idea here is to also have the return type, as opposed to `any` in his example. I dont think rewording / refactoring this question would remain the same when taking that approach and may need a new question as it is a different issue altogether (i think)? Thoughts?

Comment: This [link](https://tsplay.dev/Nn55xw) shows the types, the problem being that the types in the result function are not properly inferred

Comment: `any` as the return type was just for brevity in a comment. You can certainly use other types. I suspect that @jcalz understands your intent better than I do however since I haven't looked in detail.

Comment: Understandable, problem is, as soon as you start fiddling with results, weird things start to happen, I dont know, I think I need to make another, different issue if I am going with your approach, mostly because the entire question was based on the fact that using curried functions doesn't allow the type to propagate, now, with your approach, I have a different issue, where types somehow get scrambled, as shown in the link in the comment above

Comment: @jcalz i was experimentin with the approach you suggested and have tried to make it work by defining separate type arguments for the `dependencies` and the resulting selector, of which the type argument for the `depenecies` is expected to be explicitly set by the user. Any idea why this makes the result function's types revert to unknown / how to resolve? [TSPlayground](https://tsplay.dev/WzBBEW)

Comment: TS doesn't have partial type argument inference; it's all or nothing, see [ms/TS#26242](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) and q/a about it like [this one](//stackoverflow.com/q/74599925/2887218). I don't really know how to proceed here; if I wrote an answer it would look like "TS can't perform contextual typing back through multiple layers of function calls and you should completely refactor so that the inference works in the forward time direction" but the actual refactoring is more complicated that I want to see in an SO question; maybe we could pare the example down further?

Comment: I dont think I did partial argument inference in that last link I made, have I? I would be willing to refactor, not sure what you mean by "pare the example" ? I am assuming you mean strip down the example. I can do that, but then it will completely change the question. Does it make more sense to make, what is essentially a v2 of this question as an Edit or a new question?

Comment: ① "pare it down" is not understandable I guess?  Oh well, yeah, I meant reduce it to more of a [mre] without so many moving parts. ② "type argument explicitly set by the user" means that the ones not explicitly set by the user cannot be inferred, because there's no partial type argument inference ③ It's up to you how you want to proceed, I don't really know how to answer this question as-is without anything but "nope" which probably neither of us is much interested in, but maybe someone else will have a good approach.

Comment: I will make a new question tomorrow, implementing your suggestion from the first comment you left here and creating a more minimal reproducible example. Will post a link to that question here for reference. Thanks for all the help, happy holidays

Comment: Made the post, hopefully it targets the issue more narrowly:  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77754151)   in case any more narrowin is needed, please comment on that issue.