# Mapped type not capable of inferring exact tuple (argument) element when generics explicitly set? Any workaround?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I am having trouble understanding how/why the mapped type is unable to handle explicitly typed arguments but is working perfectly fine with default types (and is able to infer exact args)? More importantly, is there a way to keep the behavior that we see for default types, whilst constraining the arguments? Essentially is there a way to NOT lose the "tuple" whilst constraining it?

This [TSPlayground](https://tsplay.dev/wgG16w) link contains all the types / code presented in the question.

```js
type Selector<S = any, R = unknown> = (state: S) => R

type SELCTOR_NAME = keyof SELECTOR_COLLECTION

type SELECTOR_COLLECTION = {
    foo: string,
    bar: number
}

type Dependency<S = any> = SELCTOR_NAME | Selector<S>
```

Assuming all the selectors in our codebase have an entry in this collection, we could then create a function which makes a cached selector. This function would take in dependencies (which are either other `Selector`s or `SELECTOR_NAME`-ish strings) and return a memoized selector.

**For the sake of this question:** The return type of this function has been changed in order to illustrate the issue - function would, normally, return a cached selector. For that to happen however we need to map the argument types and "extract" the information regarding the return types of those arguments.

```js
declare function cachedSelector<G = any, T extends Dependency[] = Array<Dependency<G>>>(
    ...args: T
): {
        [I in keyof T]: T[I] extends SELCTOR_NAME
        ? () => SELECTOR_COLLECTION[T[I]]
        : T[I]
    }
```

Since the arguments of the function are constrained to the `T extends Dependency[]` type we have two cases:

1. Argument is a `SELECTOR_NAME`, in which case we have the information in the `SELECTORS_COLLECTION`
2. Argument is a `Selector`, in which case we have the return type present, as this is a function.

```js
// result = [() => string, () => number, () => boolean]
const result = cachedSelector("foo", "bar", () => true)
```

As we can see, this works just fine, however if we explicitly define the type argument `G` (even if we define it as it's default value `any`), the whole thing falls appart:

```js
// when explicitly defined, result = Dependency<any>[]
const result = cachedSelector<any>("foo", "bar", () => true)
// EDIT: same behavious is observed when both arguments are specified:
const resultBoth = cachedSelector<any, Dependency<any>[]>("foo", "bar", () => true)
```

To my understanding the mapping happens, but the conditional type is always `falsy`. It seems as if, when `G` is defined explicitly all the arguments simply default to being `Dependency<G>` instead of being the actual arguments that were passed to the function, so the conditional type fails.

Comment: The question is overly complicated and I am not even understanding what you are trying to achieve.  I think you should try and simplify, the requirement and the code, down to the proverbial minimal working example.

Comment: [prev question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77731944/2887218) if it's relevant for anyone.  Not sure if I want to wade into this one either, haven't had much time yet

Comment: The "wh" part was unfinished last sentence, sorry people, I must have spaced out, head is not really in the right place, very tired. As for the question, does it need to be shorter? More concise? Shall I just immediately post the "stage 3"? That would save time but might make it harder to understand? Its been a while since we last discussed it, holidays and all... haven't had the time to post earlier. What should I fix /  clarify / shorten to make this question more appealing / answerable?

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio I am not sure what do you mean by complicated> Ill give you that it is long / wall of text, but I do not think it is complicated? Is it? I've wrote this much in order to simplify it as much as possible, going as far as to explaining in simpler (stage 1) types and building on top of them until we reach the type which causes issues (stage 3). As for the minimal working example, the link provided to the TSPlayground has all the code and is easily looked at, and those same types (code) is present in the post, albeit scattered around. If its too much text, just look at stage 3

Comment: I've went ahead and reduced/edited this question further, there less than 25 lines of code, that is including the "showcase" of the error.  Hopefully it is now easier to digest and eliminates all the unnecessary fluff / reduces the issue to be closer to a minimal working example. Take a look when you have the time, thanks <3

Comment: As I mentioned in the last question, this looks like [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  You cannot specify only some type argument and have the others inferred. It's either all or nothing.  Default type arguments do not let you avoid that.  That's the basic issue in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218) and my only known approaches are laid out in that answer.  Currying looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0OJON), for example.  I'm not sure there's anything unique here that isn't duplicated there, so I'm inclined to close it.

Comment: But the same issue appears when I specify both arguemnts. The issue is not weather arguemtns are specified, but rather why, when specified, the `T[I]` no longer is a member of arguments tuple but a simple member of an array? Essentially, specifying arguments, makes the members of `...arg` no longer be tuple, rather an array, which I would like to avoid. I am looking into your currying example

Comment: I don't see you specifying both arguments. Is that shown somewhere?

Comment: Upon inspecting the example given for currying in your comment, this seems to resolve the issue that I am having, it being the fact that arguments are not tuple members but become arrays. That is something that I would say hits the crux of this question. But... if I understand correctly, this requires an additional function call yes? What is the implementation of that function (in order to not break this typing?)

Comment: "I dont see you specifying both arguments" No it isn't shown, as behavior was the same with specifying one or both - I've edited the question to show that case as well. The `arg` members became members of array instead of tuple

Comment: Yes, if you specify `Dependency<any>[]` then of course it's not a tuple anymore, because you specified it not to be one.  I'm not sure what you're expecting.  Maybe there's a more fundamental disconnect here? You need that second type argument to be a tuple type of the right shape. Either you specify it yourself, as a tuple (not as `Dependency<any>[]`, it should be the type you want it to be) or it gets inferred by the compiler.  Am I making sense so far?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a more fundamental disconnect in me not being clear on how the tuple gets inferred... but what you said last makes perfect sense, and I understand why I cannot define it, if I want it to be inferred. But in that case I ask, is there a way around it? Can the arguments be constrained while they are inferred? Essentially can `...args` be a tuple inferred by the compiler BUT under some constraint, such as with a mapped type + conditional typing?

Comment: Can you explain why currying the way shown in your example works / resolves the issues? Or direct me to the docs or some other place where it is explained. When an additional step is made (one more function call curried) this seems to work, but for the death of me I do not understand why.... I am also not sure how to write an implementation with an extra function call that doesnt really do anything, except makes sure types work

Comment: I'm almost at a loss here, since my explanation in the linked question, and your previous question, and the links to ms/TS#26242, and just... all of our recent interactions, are all about the same thing and I'm not sure I can re-explain that stuff again in some other way that you can understand. It certainly feels like there's a big communication barrier here and I don't know how to overcome it.  As for how to write it, at runtime you can always change `const f = x => ...` to `const f = () => x => ...` and then call `f()(x)` instead of `f(x)`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all the assistance, I will figure it out. You've been a lot of help, as always. The curried example works, I've adopted it in my original (more complex) typings and it seems to behave properly so I am hoping that it will work out in the end. Please do not be mad at me, I am greatful to no end for all the help you have given. Close the question if you think it is similar to the other one. Otherwise, it can remain open, or post a replay with the curried example and I will accept it. Thanks one more time

Comment: Oh my god. Okay so I totally missed the link you posted to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218) and only saw the one you posted for the TSPlayground example. It is explained very well there, everything is clear... well okay not everything I am not very sure for the use case of dummying, but I will analyze that answer in more depth. This is indeed exactly what I needed